# Duplicated records - Delete statement does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing an issue related to removing the records from my table.
Table structure:id | first_name | last_name | info | timestamp

My goal is to remove all duplicated records which have got this same first_name and timestamp. Example:

- 10,Mariusz,Jablko,Smieszny,1635837167
- 198,Mariusz,Smieszek,Zwariowany,1635837167
- 285,Mariusz,Ogien,Smutny,1635837168

So, I would like to remove the record with id = 198 (This same first_name and timestamp as 10).

I tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM people p1 
 INNER JOIN people p2 on p1.first_name = p2.first_name 
        AND p1.timestamp = p2.timestamp 
      WHERE p1.id < p2.id
```

I do not know why, but it does not work.
Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mention - SQL.

Comment: "doesn't work", does that mean nothing was deleted? What if you (as a test) replace that `DELETE` with a `SELECT *`?

Comment: "sql" is not a dbms. Is it SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, ...? Please [add that tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/388760#388760)

Comment: Hey @MariuszAdamczewski, add your `p1.timestamp = p2.timestamp` into `where clause` itself and check whether it works

Comment: Wouldn't you need `WHERE p1.id > p2.id` to delete the higher ID number?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server the use Common table expression, the following query will delete all duplicate records:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY first_name ,timestamp  ORDER BY timestamp )
   FROM people 
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: They are using `mysql`

Comment: The ROW_NUMBER() function has been supported since MySQL version 8.02 .So it will work for that or upper version

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. This syntax is SQL Server propriatary. After making your statement a tad more standard compliant by replacing `rn = ...` by `... AS rn`, MySQL still fails with "The target table CTE of the DELETE is not updatable". I don't see, why MySQL considers the CTE not updateable, but other DBMS like Oracle or PostgreSQL don't support this syntax either.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the DBMS which of the two tables to delete from (`DELETE p1 FROM ...`). And in order to keep the lower ID you need `WHERE p1.id > p2.id` instead of `WHERE p1.id < p2.id`.

```
DELETE p1 
 FROM people p1 
 INNER JOIN people p2 ON p1.first_name = p2.first_name 
                     AND p1.timestamp = p2.timestamp 
                     AND p1.id > p2.id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=506708ccceca6217d783b8477f3ec247